# Date stamp script not working with arrayformula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to use a simple date stamp script in Google Sheets that will input today's date upon edit of another column but then will not change thereafter. I also have an array formula set on the column the script is looking at for the edits and it appears the array formula is preventing the script from working properly. Here is the formula:

```
={"Triggered";arrayformula(IFS(E2:E="","",C2:C>=E2:E,"✅",TRUE,""))}
```

And this is the script:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sh.getName() !== "Watchlist" || e.range.columnStart !== 8) return;// 1 is A, 2 is B, 3 is C, etc
  var o = e.range.offset(0, 1)
  if(!o.getValue()) o.setValue(new Date())
}
```

Any help with what I'm doing wrong is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here's the link to the sheet. The formula issue is in column J (Triggered).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WxVCEpG9HPz2JnVBjhrfAJicaALL282c2i2sUxshlC0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: would you let us copy the file so we can help you out?

Comment: Sure. Do I need to change a setting on the sheet?

Comment: I think this will work.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WxVCEpG9HPz2JnVBjhrfAJicaALL282c2i2sUxshlC0/copy

Comment: @AndyMilligan please make it public

Comment: "it appears the array formula is preventing the script from working properly" - can you add more info whats your issue ?

Comment: I think onEdit won't fire if there is a change from arrayformulas or importranges etc.. Because these changes won't edit the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) :

> An installable edit trigger runs when a user **modifies** a value in a
> spreadsheet.

Even when the output of the arrayformula is updated, the cell still contains the same formula. Therefore, the onEdit trigger won't fire since there wasn't any edit action by the user.

Read also the discussion [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104025/trigger-function-when-importrange-is-updated).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Any idea on a workaround or alternative method?

Comment: Maybe a time-driven trigger will do the job. Run a function that monitors changes in the values of the cells on a time basis. Then, if there is a change, update the timestamp.